# C++ optimization of local variable used for DMA

Tags: c++

I have a bug in an embedded application that I'm not sure the best way to solve. I have a local variable for which I use the address as a pointer for a dma transfer. I do this a bit in the program, but only recently did it cause a failure. I think this is because optimization is reclaiming the memory for other purposes after the address is used in the program but before the dma transfer occurs. Example:

```
struct {
    volatile uint32_t address_ptr;
} DMA;

void spi_write(uint8_t *data) {
  DMA.address_ptr = reinterpret_cast<volatile uint32_t>(data);
}

main() {
  uint8_t data_out[2] = {0xAB, 0xCD};
  spi_write(data_out);
}
```

The result on spi is that random numbers are sent out. I can fix it by making data_out into a global variable. So I assume that the C compiler is assuming that it can use the `data_out` memory for other purposes after `DMA.address_ptr` has been set. I can't think of a way to prevent this from happening. Is there a way to prevent this from getting optimized like this? Or is there some other mistake?

The processor is an STM32 cortex M4. In both the optimized and unoptimized cases the DMA address points to an area of memory this is accessible to it (0x20000000 block). The issue shows itself independent of memory location: [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:14,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:14,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:14,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:14),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstdint%3E%0A%0Astruct+%7B%0A++++volatile+uint32_t+address_ptr%3B%0A%7D+DMA%3B%0A%0Avoid+spi_write(uint8_t+*data)+%7B%0A++DMA.address_ptr+%3D+reinterpret_cast%3Cvolatile+uint32_t%3E(data)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Amain()+%7B%0A++uint8_t+data_out%5B2%5D+%3D+%7B0xAB,+0xCD%7D%3B%0A++spi_write(data_out)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:armg1320,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+ARM+GCC+13.2.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

---

Adding some additional debugging based on the comments and tinkering with godbolt compiler explorer. I'm using arm gcc 32 bit, Though I did find that clang does not seem to optimize out the assignment. At -O0 there is a definite initialization of data_out with the value 52651, which is 0xCDAB.

```
movw    r3, #52651
```

At any higher level of optimization that instruction is removed. But the program doesn't optimize to nothing. In fact it appears to just load `DMA.address_ptr` with some uninitialized memory from the stack. This seems to also be what is happening in my larger program. If I make `address_ptr` non-volatile, then it will optimize to nothing. So far I've found three solutions that will keep the assignment.

- Declare spi_write as `spi_write(volatile uint8_t *data)`
- Insert an assembly instruction somewhere. It can be anything `asm("nop");`
- Make `data_out` a static const global. It does get initialized.

I don't understand if of these solutions is a good way of dealing with the problem.

Comment: Before applying any optimization, generate an assembly language listing.  Verify that the compiler has not removed any assembly language statements.  Next, try declaring the pointer as "pointer to volatile data".  Generate the assembly language listing.  Verify the assembly language.

Comment: how variable `length` is used in the `spi_write`?

Comment: Don't delay for the DMA or SPI bus.  Prefer interrupts.  Otherwise, *poll* to verify that the data has been transmitted.  A 3 microseconds may not always be correct.  Also, use an outer loop for limiting the polling iterations.

Comment: The life-time of `data_out` will be until the `main` function returns. I.e. the full run-time of the program. However, it might be located in a memory segment that isn't possible to do DMA from? What is the hardware you're targeting? What CPU are you using? How is the memory setup?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Good advice. It seems that 0xABCD is optimized out for anything greater than -O0. [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/rjWs6c8KG). Setting those variables as volatile does keep 0xABCD. Is there any other way to specify this without volatile?

Comment: Why don’t you want to use `volatile`? That’s what it’s *for,* among other things.

Comment: Your godbolt example doesn't mean anything to me.  The program doesn't do anything.  No I/O, no external linkage.  The whole program can be optimized to nothing.

Answer (score 2):

(a) Nothing in your program informs the compiler that `data_out` will be read. Its address is put into `DMA.address_ptr`, and `DMA_address_ptr` is volatile, so that tells the compiler something will read the address. But that is insufficient to tell the compiler that the bytes in `data_out` are read by anything. Since the compiler has no reason to believe the bytes will be read, it has no reason to store anything in the bytes. So the compiler is allowed to optimize away writes to `data_out`, including its initialization. To fix that, declare `data_out` with `volatile`.

(b) Nothing in your program waits for the DMA to complete. Even if `data_out` were declared `static`, the program could terminate before the DMA completes. Maybe the DMA is completing, on those occasions when it works, before the procedure of terminating the program is complete (`main` returns, exit functions are performed, a call is made to the operating system to terminate the process, and the operating system reclaims memory). You should have something in your program that waits for the DMA to complete.

Once you have that something, you can release the memory of `data_out`. It could be automatic in `main` (or another routine) and you return from `main` (or that other routine), it could be `static` and your program returns from `main`, it could be dynamically allocated and your program frees it. In any case, those are the two pieces you need:

- You must declare `data_out` with `volatile` to inform the compiler the contents of `data_out` are read by means otherwise unknown to the compiler.
- Your program must wait for the DMA to complete before it releases the memory of `data_out`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to prevent this from getting optimized like this?

Portably? No.

What you want is:

1. static variables, and
2. don't return from `main`.

Static variables are guaranteed to exist while the body of `main` is executing. So, when `main` is entered, the static variables were already initialized, and they will exist until `main` is returned from.

So, the simple fix is:

```
main() {
  static uint8_t data_out[2] = {0xAB, 0xCD};
  spi_write(data_out);
  while (true);
}
```

Note that static lifetime is needed. Just looping at the end of `main` will not necessarily fix it:

```
main() {
  uint8_t data_out[2] = {0xAB, 0xCD};
  spi_write(data_out);
  while (true);
}
```

That's because the *C code* does not access `data_out` after the `spi_write` function has returned. So the lifetime of `data_out`, from the point of view of C code, is over anyway, since there's no code that could use `data_out`.

The `static` storage class, on the other hand, does exactly what you'd want for a DMA access: it ensures that the variable is live as long as the main thread of execution is within the `main` body. So, `static` in combination with an endless loop, is one way to do it portably.

The loop could also monitor the DMA status to detect end of transfer, and break when the DMA transfer is over. At that time the SPI peripheral may still be busy transmitting data, so to be completely safe from variations in the hardware abstraction code, you'd want to either delay (sleep) a fixed time after the DMA transfer is over, or, after the DMA transfer is done, monitor the SPI busy status, and only exit when SPI is not busy. **Do not** skip the DMA transfer status, since otherwise there can be a race condition when you happen to "catch" SPI being idle "between the bytes" while the DMA transfer is still ongoing and the next byte will be loaded into the SPI transmit register shortly. Only by *first* waiting for DMA transfer to end, and *then* waiting for the SPI peripheral to become idle you can be reasonably sure that the loop (and thus `main`) can be exited.

There's nothing wrong with just sticking an endless loop at the end of `main`, though - simple and effective.

The body of the wait loop can have an `asm("halt");` inside of it, to conserve power.

---

There is no optimization. Your `data_out` was an automatic variable that was in scope from its definition until the end of the block. Since you exited from main, `data_out` ceased to exist as well. It's not the compiler doing it, it's your code telling the compiler to do it - via the semantics of the C language. In other words, the compiler doesn't "optimize" anything necessarily. It just does what the standard expects it to do, whereas your code assumed variable lifetime that was nowhere to be found in the C standard.

Comment: Endless loop with no side effects is UB... maybe should be noted somewhere.

Comment: This is a very good answer, but I'm not sure it is the answer to my question. Adding while(true) to the code in the godbolt complier, it still never loads the values 0xAB,0xCD, when optimization is greater than -O0. I assume this is because the complier doesn't see any way in which I'm using those values.

Comment: "There is no optimization" is wrong.  There is optimization, but it's a perfectly permitted optimization, obeying the as-if rule.